# Should I submit original or copy of my passport to Canadian embassy for an immigration application?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada

Recently my husband applied for my immigration to canada in Family Class. My husband is a canadian citizen. Recently I have been asked to submit as the following

> Passport/Travel Document: Valid passport or travel document  This must be received at this office by: 2019/07/10

I am wondering whether they asked me to submit my original passport or a copy?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

They're going to stick an actual physical visa into your actual passport, so a copy won't suffice.
Send the real thing.

Your husband probably already gave them a copy when your application was submitted.

Answer (score 6):

A copy of your passport isn't a valid passport or travel document. They want the actual passport.

Comment: Helps to explain why.

Comment: @Harper The question asks if a copy is enough. I have explained that it isn't. _Why_ it's not enough doesn't really matter: in practical terms, "Because, if you don't, you don't get your visa."

Answer (score 1):

My wife had to send her passport to The Philippines (she was in Japan). After they received it with her application, they said that her medical certificate was too old and she needed a new one.

But to get it she had to take her passport to the doctor.

But they had her passport.

In the end, it took me getting our Member of Parliament's office involved, because the Philippines office didn't respond to my emails or faxes (there was no phone number). They sent it back to her, by collect courier -- for which she had to pay almost $200!

So yes, you have to send in your passport, even though it seems sketchy, and hopefully your experience isn't as bad as ours!

Comment: Do you have verifiable sources to confirm this?

Comment: @JJJ: That is rather a silly question, if you ask me. Graham is hardly likely to upload the correspondence for us to see, is he? Either you believe him or you don't.

Comment: @TonyK surely there is some information by the country (e.g. on embassy / government website) to send the real document if that is what they require. It's a bit silly to have answers which aren't supported by evidence. Indeed, that opens a whole world of statements and promises which may or may not be true undermining the purpose of this site.

Comment: @JJJ: are you suggesting that the Visa Department of the Canadian Embassy in the Philippines might confirm that in 2009 they accepted a Permanent Residency application and then demanded a new medical certificate while still being in possession of the passport? When they wouldn't even respond to emails and faxes at the time? Or that I have kept the documentation of the application for 10 years after Residency was granted?

Comment: @Graham no, I'm saying their website will have general information about common procedures which the questions asks about (in particular, whether a copy of a passport suffices or not).

Comment: @JJJ: I see, I misunderstood what you were asking. But since the PR (or any visa) is entered directly onto the passport page, the original passport is clearly required. I have heard that people entering Israel can have their visa stamped onto a removable page (because otherwise they would be banned from entering certain Muslim countries if the immigration officers see an Israeli stamp), but never heard of it for anywhere else.

Comment: @Graham yea I think a copy isn't very useful most of the time. Not sure about this case because it doesn't explicitly mention visa. Also, I'd be a bit worried about sending passports via the post (even though it's common practice).

Comment: Do I need to send them prepaid envelop with my passport to give it back to me?

Comment: @S786: Sorry, I don't know (and the procedures now may well be different than they were when we did it. I'm sure that would be part of the information that they gave you when they asked for the passport.